# How to get a selection of tracks using the duration range

Tags: android, playlist, mediastore, playlists

I am trying to select tracks using duration ranges.
for instance

```
String start = null;
String end = null;
if (criteria == getString(R.string.uptofivemins)) {
    start = "0";
    end = "300000";
}
String[] crit =  {start,end};
String where = "duration >= ? AND duration < ? ";
//.... 


private final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
private final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;
//etc...
cr.query(uri, columns, where, crit, null);
```

Problem appears to be that as I need to feed in Strings start and end, the resulting query will execute using these. The database field "duration" however is of type int and from the results that are returned I suspects that the comparison is against strings rather than int so the selection is incorrect.
Anyone with ideas on how to select tracks using duration ranges eg < 5 mins, between 5 and 10 mins, etc.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'criteria' seems to be of type String. If so, why don't you use 'String.equals()' for the comparison?

Comment: Also, you can convert Strings to ints and ints to Strings if you need to. Use `String.valueOf(int)` and `Integer.parseInt(string)`

Comment: I am familiar with the methods but the problem lies with passing the values to the query. crit only takes strings not int .

Comment: 1. good, you changed the query ("crit" instead of "criteria") - I was almost sure that could only be a typo    2. from my own experience, it's no problem to feed {"5", "30"} to a query. If the respective columns are declared as numbers the database will read the input as numbers. So if you get unexpected results, I still suspect the comparison (criteria == getString(R.string.uptofivemins) ) to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was sorted. A combination of human error and impatience. 
Query executes against the audio table

```
   SELECT duration FROM audio WHERE duration >= '300000' AND duration <= '600000';
```